# How to make trail renderer not affected by z axis motion in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making a 3D game and I made input collector that has trail renderer component. When there is z action motion the trailer renderer shows some forward motion effects.

Is there any way to make trail renderer only show certain axis motion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to make a separate object with trail, and move it to the position of the object you want to have a trail on before rendering starts, and then, on post render, reset its Z position. Like this:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(TrailRenderer))]
public class ZLimitedTrail : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;        

    private void Start() {
        Camera.onPreRender += SetPosition;
        Camera.onPostRender += ResetZPosition;
    }

    private void SetPosition() {
        // move it to where it should show
        this.transform.position = target.position;
    }

    private void ResetZPosition() {
        // reset Z position to 0
        this.transform.position = 
            new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y, 0);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it so let me know if it works.